# Eclipse and JavaFX? is it just me?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm looking at learning JavaFX.

I've tried setting Eclipse to develop a small app and I've downloaded the Eclipse plugin.

[Eclipse JavaFX plugin](http://javafx.com/docs/gettingstarted/eclipse-plugin/)

BUT... it just seems, well, flakey.

So I have 3 questions...

1: Is there a better plugin?

2: Or is there some great set of tutorials out there that I'm missing?

3: finally, is it meant to be easy to call Java code from FX? I'm stuggling, it there a good example somewhere?

On questions 1 & 2, Eclipse underlines code in red that just shouln't be. For example..
see this image... [alt text http://www.qenet.co.uk/fx.jpg](http://www.qenet.co.uk/fx.jpg)

Why does it underline bit of imports in red?

I know this is little of an open ended question. So I guess my main question is this...

Is my experiance of JavaFX and Eclipse the best I can hope for? Or am I missing something ?
(and I'm not looking for a Yes/No response) :-)

Just looking for a discussion on how best to learn/develop JavaFx.

Comment: This question needs to be worded better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing is not unusual.  A lot of Eclipse plugin editors have problems dealing with error tags and the like.  For example,

- I find that the XML and HTML file editors often fail to clear error and warning markers, and the only way to get rid of the markers it is close and reopen the file.
- Even the Java viewer gets it wrong in some circumstances, though the problem goes away when the relevant files are saved.
- When you update a spelling dictionary, the spelling checker is not rerun and the spelling error markers are not updated.  In fact, you have to restart Eclipse for this to happen.

I suggest that you try saving files, and closing/reopening editors to see if that makes the bogus error markers go away.  Then decide whether Eclipse is the right IDE for this task.

I've never used NetBeans (at all), but you would expect that it would do a better job supporting JavaFX.  After all NetBeans and JavaFX are both high profile Sun products at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Stephen. I might try giving Netbeans a poke tonight. I'd intentionally left FX for a few months after release in the hope that these issues would, well, not be issues.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is really the only way to go at the moment for JavaFX development. They are both Sun products and Sun has made sure the two work very well together. Before long Eclipse and others will catch up but for the moment that's how it is.

Answer (score 1):

There is another JavaFX plug-in for Eclipse from Exadel. You can download it here: http://exadel.org/javafxplugin. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems but funnily only under Linux, not Windows. Hope they change that soon.

Answer (score 0):

To me this has happened when I wronlgy installed javafx sdk 1.2.3....This plugin works only with 1.2.1... :/